# How to kill an individual request in an IIS worker process?

Tags: .net, iis-8, application-pool, worker-process

**The environment**
We are running IIS 8 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and have a a number of .net web apps running all using their own application pools.

**The problem**
Occasionally, due to a yet to be determined reason, we get a specific request in the app pool for one of our .Net MVC apps that seems to be stuck/looping and accruing large amounts of elapsed time. I monitor this by using the "worker Processes" function in the IIS Management Console and double clicking on the specific application pool that is using high cpu and memory.

**Findings so far**
So far when this problem occurs the only way I have been able to get rid of it is to manually recycle the app pool, waiting for the nightly scheduled app pool recycle or do an IIS reset. Unfortunately this has unintended side effects, namely kicking everyone out of the web site. Extensive searching for solutions hasn't been fruitful and a post on iis.net suggest it cant be done.

Has anyone found a better way to do this until i can ascertain the root cause and prevent it from occurring in the first place?

Additionally, I am open to doing this via IIS, script, in code or 3rd party utility.

Comment: any luck?  I haven't found anything to kill an individual worker process either....  I don't like having to restart app pool, site, iisreset, or reboot... but appears to be the only approach at the moment ?

Comment: I am still facing this issue did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No sorry I didn't unfortunately.